# Error when connecting spark structured streaming + kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

im trying to connect my structured streaming spark 2.4.5 with kafka, but all the times that im trying this Data Source Provider errors appears.
Follow my scala code and my sbt build:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger

object streaming_app_demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println("Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka Demo Application Started ...")

    val KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "test"
    val KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "test"
    val KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS = "localhost:9092"


    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka Demo")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    // Stream from Kafka
    val df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS)
      .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS)
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .load()

    val ds = df
      .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("topic", "test2")
      .start()
  }
}
```

And the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:652)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:161)
    at streaming_app_demo$.main(teste.scala:29)
    at streaming_app_demo.main(teste.scala)
```

And my sbt.build is:

```
name := "scala_212"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.5" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "2.5.0"
```

Thank You !

Comment: I have change my 11 line in sbt.build to:
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.5"
And my code finally works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `spark structured streaming + kafka`, this spark-sql-kafka-0-10 library required.

You are getting this `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka` exception because `spark-sql-kafka` library is not available in your classpath & It is unable to find `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister` inside META-INF/services folder.

`DataSourceRegister path inside jar file`

/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.2.0/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister

`Update`

If you are using SBT, try add below code block. This will include `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister` file in your final jar.

```
// META-INF discarding
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF","services",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case PathList("META-INF",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: So, i change my library to:
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.5"
And my code finally works. How i put this packges in pyspark ? I have to download spark-sql-kafka-0-10 jar and put in spark jars directory?

Comment: are you using sbt ?

Comment: With pyspark, no

Comment: but in your question you added sbt build file ?, If you are using sbt use above code so that it will automatically add file to your final jar file.

Comment: Yes, but i create this project with intelli j. So i dont download the spark file like i do when i wnat to run pyspark and i wnat to add to my pyspark this "spark-sql-kafka-0-10 dependencie for run structured streaming with pyspark